# Generate attack graph by mulval

Tags: centos7, xsb

I have installed Mulval successfully.
The problem is : I have not get the AttackGraph.pdf by using the coding "graph_gen.sh /root/data/mulval/testcases/3host/input.P -v".

Comment: But i get these results as:
AttackGraph.txt,
AttackGraph.xml,
AttackGraph.dot,
AttackGraph.eps,
ARCS.CSV,
and other *.P  .

Comment: I want to know where is the "AttackGraph.pdf"?

Answer (score 0):

May I know, 
system give the tip: render.sh: epstopdf : have not find the order.

the reason is : the "eps" file have not translated the "pdf" file.
Because i use the centos7 , not the Ubantu,  Maybe system need the transfor tool.